# Form submit on keyCode == "enter" (13)

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

I need to submit the content of a form when I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, but only if the form has no error message. I built up the following function:

```
$(targetFormID).submit(function (e) {
    var mess = error_m(targetDiv);
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && mess.length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    if (mess.length == 0 && e.keyCode == 13) $(targetFormID).submit();
});
```

In this function the mess variable is getting the error message returned by function `error_m`, the rest is simple code condtion but it doesn't work.

Need some help with this!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Submitting the form when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed is default browser behaviour. Don't mess with it. Just validate the form in the `submit` event.

```
$(targetFormID).submit(function (e) {
    var mess = error_m(targetDiv);
    if (mess.length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

One other possible problem: what is `targetFormID`? If it's actually a string containing an element ID, you'll need

```
$("#" + targetFormID).submit(/* Same function as above */);
```

If it's a reference to the form element then `$(targetFormID)` is fine but your variable is misleadingly named.

Comment: If you have multiple forms on the page, you might have to implement such a solution, especially if focus often is not on one of the form elements of the "default" form  (well, that's what I remember from having to do something like this over 4 years ago).