# jQuery inline edit return key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a working inline edit script which lets the user edit his or her name.

But it currently does not "save" when the user hits the `enter key`

The script:

```
<span class="pageTitle" id="username">Visitor 123123981203980912 <span class="iconb" data-icon=""></span></span> 

    // Inline edit
    $.fn.inlineEdit = function(replaceWith, connectWith) {

        $(this).hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        });

        $(this).click(function() {

            var elem = $(this);

            elem.hide();
            elem.after(replaceWith);
            replaceWith.focus();

            replaceWith.blur(function() {

                if ($(this).val() != "") {
                    connectWith.val($(this).val()).change();
                    elem.html($(this).val() + ' <span class="iconb" data-icon=""></span>');
                }

                $(this).remove();
                elem.show();
            });
        });
    };

    var replaceWith = $('<input name="temp" type="text" class="inlineEdit" />'),
        connectWith = $('input[name="hiddenField"]');

    $('#username').inlineEdit(replaceWith, connectWith);
```

How can i make the above also react when the `enter key` is hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detect the enter press and do the same thing in blur function. Add the following to your js. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/63DPW/)

```
    replaceWith.keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                connectWith.val($(this).val()).change();
                elem.html($(this).val() + ' <span class="iconb" data-icon=""></span>');
            }

            $(this).remove();
            elem.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fire when the enter key is pressed inside the input:

```
$('#username').live("keypress", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            // action here
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the same function on keydown and check for e.keyCode for enter key which is 13..a fiddle would be helpful..

Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803376/form-submit-on-keycode-enter-13)

Thanks,
Hardik